# Installing Jruby changes default paths of Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Rails, and have been following the tutorial on this website: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I installed Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2.6.  I used `rvm` to install Ruby and `gem` to install Rails.

To start the web server, I need to have a Javascript runtime. I choose therubyrhino. To install it, I need to first install JRuby.  I used `gem` to install it

```
$ rvm install jruby
```

After that I found that the default path of Ruby and Rails are both changed to:

```
~/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin/rails
~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin/ruby
```

This causes problems because I even cannot run

```
$ ruby -v
```

or

```
$ rails -v
```

I could not start the web server

```
$  bin/rails server
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String
   join at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1760
  <top> at /home/jxw394/rails-projects/blog/bin/spring:11
   load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
  <top> at bin/rails:3
```

Why does installing JRuby change everything?  What should I do to get the webapp running?

**Edit:** sorry I made a typo: it should be "therubyrhino" instead of "therubyracer". This has been corrected above.

Edit: sorry, I made a typo: I installed jruby using rvm instead of gem. This has been corrected above.

Comment: You cannot use `gem install jruby` because there is no such gem, and Jruby cannot be installed as a gem. Follow the installation instructions from the documentation: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: sorry, that was another typo. I used rvm to install jruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `jruby` in order to install `therubyracer`. You only need to comment out `therubyracer` entry in `Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

One another way which doesn't involve `therubyracer` is to install node.js.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo: it should be  "therubyrhino" instead of "therubyracer". "the rubyrhino" does not appear in Gemfile.

Comment: Eventually, I removed ruby, jruby, and rails. Reinstalled rvm from its website, and reinstalled ruby, jruby, and rails using rvm commands. I did not use therubyrhino because it does not appear in Gemfile. I just un-comment the line containing therubyrace, run bundle install and then I could start the server. I check your answer as it appears correct.

Comment: One thing you need to note here is jruby is an alternative to ruby. You can either use jruby or use ruby. If you are using jruby, you might need to use therubyrhino instead of therubyracer